# How to add tangents to bubbles

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I am building a very simple bubble chart with just 2 observations.
I would like to add a tanget to each bubble to add the labels later. The point of contact should be at the top or bottom of each bubble.

*Example:*

```
library("ggplot2") 
df <- data.frame(group=c(FALSE,TRUE),
                 value=c(5,30))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=group, 
                 y=0,
                 size=value,
                 fill=group),
             shape=21) +
  scale_size_area(max_size=25) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: without tangents]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: with tangents]

My best guess how to do this would be adding something like:

```
...  
annotate("segment",
           x = 0.2, xend = 1, 
           y = pointOfContact_1, yend = pointOfContact_1) +
annotate("segment",
           x = 2.8, xend = 2, 
           y = pointOfContact_2, yend = pointOfContact_2)
```

However, I don't know how to calculate the points of contact (y-values).
Looking into `ggplot_build()` didn't help me either so far...

Any ideas?

Comment: `geom_point` will scale when the plot size changes. One solution would be to plot the circles with `geom_polygon` instead, then you can reliably calculate the points of contact (center +- radius).

Comment: mh...if it can't be done with `geom_point`, maybe `ggforce::geom_circle()` is the easier way to go than `geom_polygon`

Comment: Yeah sure thing. It will be much less painful than dealing with changing scaling etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right that `ggforce::geom_circle` is the way to go. I tried several options, including some labeling approaches, and I couldn't make progress. But, `geom_circle` worked very slick. You need to take a bit of care with setting the radius size, and with how you place the x coordinates, but this seems to work smoothly:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0=as.numeric(group), 
                  y0=0,
                  r=value/100,
                  fill=group)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(group),
                   xend = as.numeric(group) + ifelse(as.numeric(group) == 1, 0.5, -0.5),
                   y = 0 + value/100,
                   yend = 0 + value/100
                   )) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

gives

[image]

If you have more than two points, you will likely want to set the `xend` outside of `ggplot` by adding a column giving the location. Similarly, you may want to do radius and location in the data directly as well.

Here is an example calculating these metrics before passing the data to `ggplot`. I moved things around just because I could, and to show the types of things you could set up.

```
data.frame(xloc = c(1, 2, 1, 2)
           , yloc = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
           , value = 1:4) %>%
  mutate(radius = value / 10
         , xend = ifelse(xloc < 1.5, xloc - 0.5, xloc + 0.5)
         , ystart = ifelse(yloc < 1.5, yloc - radius, yloc + radius)
         , yend = ifelse(yloc < 1.5
                         , ystart - 0.25
                         , ystart + 0.25)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0=xloc, 
                  y0=yloc,
                  r=radius,
                  fill= paste(xloc, yloc)) ) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = xloc,
                   xend = xend,
                   y = ystart,
                   yend = yend
  )) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

gives

[image]